# Adding data from API as new entry to ListView

Tags: flutter

I'm getting data from an API `productObject` and display them in the build widget as follows:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_sharedText != null) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Thank you"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade400,
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<ProductInformationModel>(
              future: productObject(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ProductInformationModel> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return
                    ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 2, //just a number to display at least the result
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Container(
                            //height: 75,
                            child: Center(
                              child: midView(snapshot),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                    );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Container(child:
                  Text("${snapshot.error}"));
                } else {
                  return Container(
                    child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),
                  );
```

This is ok so far, but what I want is that every time the API is called again the present displayed API output will remain displayed on the screen and the new called API output will be visible below the present output.
So each API call should be one list entry without deleting the former data from the API.

An example of the productObject:

```
  Future<ProductInformationModel> productObject({String urlName}) async {
    try {
      return new Network().getProductInformation(urlName: _sharedText);

    } catch (e) {
      print("Image not found: $e");
    }
  }
```

And I call the API like this:

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      model (ProductInformationModel from product_information_model.dart
      print("image data: ${response.body}");
      return ProductInformationModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }else {
      throw Exception("Error getting image info");
    }
```

```
Widget midView(AsyncSnapshot<ProductInformationModel> snapshot) {
  var productName = snapshot.data.objects[0].title;
  var productImage = snapshot.data.objects[0].images[0].url;
  var api_type = snapshot.data.request.api;
  var pageUrl_type = snapshot.data.request.pageUrl;
  Container midView = Container(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[Text("$productName, $productImage",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 18,
          color: Colors.black87
        ),),
```

I think I need the `setState()` but where do I set it?
Do I need to create an empty list before?

Thanks a lot, I'm new to flutter and struggle with this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues that I can see, but I can't offer you a complete solution without seeing the rest of the code (`midView` Widget). You have your `ListView.builder` with a fixed `itemCount` of `2` but then you are passing the whole snapshot to the `midView` Widget. I would actually have expected that the snapshot's data was a list, and you would cycle through the list using the `index` provided by the `builder`. That would also mean that you would set the `itemCount` not as a fixed value but as the length of the list coming from your snapshot. The following code assumes that your snapshot is a List:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data['objects'].length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: midView(snapshot.data['objects'][index]),
      ),
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi Joao, thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, you are right, `snapshot` is not a list but of type `AsyncSnapshot<ProductInformationModel>`. How can I transform it into a list to follow your example? Thank you.

Comment: If you share on your question an example of your `ProductInformationModel`, I should be able to help.

Comment: Thanks Joao, I added an example and how I call the API

Comment: So it's the "objects" inside the Model that you want to list?

Comment: You didn't share the code I asked about, `midView`. But from what I can see, you should be able to just access the objects array of your Model directly. I've added it to my code.

Comment: sorry, added midView: If I follow your example I get an error at snapshot.length because snapshot isn't a list. How can I change <Future> from the API to a list to be displayed? Or is it possible to display a <Future> as a new list entry? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are right, I need to make more modification to the code to accommodate for the new information you shared.

Comment: @user3469337 Please check the changes. I've modified both the `itemCount` and the data in the `mideView`.

Comment: thanks, now I get this error at the line with snapshot['objects'].length: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<ProductInformationModel>'

Comment: I believe it was missing the `.data` property to access the data coming from the `snapshot`. I've made the correction.

Comment: Has it fixed your issue?

Comment: thank you very much. `itemCount: snapshot.data.objects.length`, is working fine but `midView(snapshot)` not (just the solution here). The `[index]` is not usable. And by doing so the first and only entry will always be replaced. Didn't we need to use setState for that? thanks

Comment: I can't see your data. But The FutureBuilder should be doing that for you. Regardless, there are other ways of implement this. Using a listener and saving the data every time there is a change pushed by snapshot, then calling a setState so that the list gets updated. I would have to write all of that code now to show you.

Comment: Can you share your `productObject()` method?

Comment: added productObject()